# Is it possible to read a modified json file without rebuilding the project in Scala?

Tags: scala

After I change the configuration in the **app.json** file, when the project starts, **the new changes are not applied** and **I have to rebuild the project** (build new jar file). Is it possible to make this code read the modified app.json without rebuilding whole project?

Below is a package reading data from a **app.json** file

```
import net.liftweb.json._
import scala.io._

case class KafkaConfiguration(bootstrap_servers: String,
                              topic_extractor: String,
                              topic_vertica: String,
                              message_max_bytes: String,
                              group_id: String
                             )

case class HbaseConfiguration(table_name: String= "test", batch_size: Int)

case class SparkConfiguration(id: String, frequency: Int)

case class VerticaConfiguration(vertica_delimiter: String, vertica_qv: String)


case class Configuration(kafka: KafkaConfiguration,
                         spark: SparkConfiguration,
                         hbase: HbaseConfiguration,
                         vertica: VerticaConfiguration)

object Configuration{
  def getConfiguration(filePath: String = "app.json"): Configuration ={
    implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
    val json = Source.fromURL(getClass.getClassLoader.getResource(filePath), "utf-8").mkString
    val jValue = parse(json)
    val kafkaConf = jValue.\("kafka").extract[KafkaConfiguration]
    val sparkConfig = jValue.\("spark").extract[SparkConfiguration]
    val hbaseConfig = jValue.\("hbase").extract[HbaseConfiguration]
    val verticaConfig = jValue.\("vertica").extract[VerticaConfiguration]
    val configuration: Configuration = new Configuration(kafkaConf, sparkConfig, hbaseConfig,verticaConfig)
    configuration
  }
}
```

Script to run my application:

```
. /etc/spark2/conf/spark-env.sh
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_201-amd64
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
export SPARK_KAFKA_VERSION=0.10

CONFIG_FILE="app.json"
COMMAND="spark2-submit \
--master yarn \
--num-executors 4 \
--driver-memory 1g \
--executor-memory 2g \
 --deploy-mode cluster \
 --name "app1" \
 --class DataPointStreaming ./app1.jar $CONFIG_FILE"
 echo $COMMAND exec $COMMAND
```

Comment: What's the thing you need to keep changing with every run? To avoid having to recompile you can 1. read values from env variables 2. override options using jvm `-D` flags 3. move out things from the config if they don't really belong there

Comment: Thanks. Sometimes i should change servers hostnames and etc. I edited description and showed script to run my application. It should be ok, but i don't know why it doesn't work without recompiling. Thanks, i'll try later

Comment: You can also replace JSON with HOCON and Typesafe Config. Then you'll be able to override config values using JVM parameters.

Comment: The problem is your `app.json` file is included in the `.jar` file. Even if you change `app.json`, in the `.jar` there is still the old version which keeps to be used, hence the need to rebuild the project (create new `.jar`). You might read the `app.json` from some other path, not from the `.jar`, but it's better as others advised - to move some config values outside of the file to env vars or java properties.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Spark, taking advantage of HOCON's environment variable substitution or even JVM properties might not be workable, as the JAR will be shipped across a cluster.

It is posssible to replace a file in a JAR (or, more formally, build a new JAR based on a given JAR with a file added).  Something along these lines in bash can work:

```
#!/bin/sh

base=$( basename -- "$1" )
filename="${base%.*}"

config=$( basename -- "$2" )
confignoext="${config%.*}"

tmpdir=$( mktemp -d )
tmpdest="$tmpdir/$base"
confdest="$tmpdir/app.json"

cp $1 $tmpdest
cp $2 $confdest

zip -jur $tmpdest $confdest

mkdir -p build/configured
dest=build/configured/$filename-$confignoext.jar

cp $tmpdest $dest
echo $dest
```

Then you don't have to recompile everything to build a jar, you just keep a set of json files to patch into the jar for deployment (e.g. `app-dev.json`, `app-prod.json`, etc.)

Comment: Do you mean that this script will help to build every new jar (without recompiling) every time I change the app.json (config json file)?

Comment: Yeah you have an existing jar and this script will copy a file from outside the jar into the jar.